# Image File Not Being Saved in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, postman, multer

I am using MERN technologies to create a news article web application.

**To do this, I have the following Mongoose Schema:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Article = new Schema({
    article_title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    article_summary: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    article_content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    article_image: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    article_reference: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', Article);
```

**And the following Express server, where I have a post method that above informations as a "req.body" and "req.file" to save in db using Mongoose and Multer:**

```
const multer = require('multer');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const articleRoutes = express.Router();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

let Article = require('./article.model');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/article', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function() {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "images");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + "--" + file.originalname);
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

articleRoutes.route("/content-management-system/add").post(upload.single("article_image"), (req, res) => {
    console.log("START FROM HERE");
    const article = new Article({
        article_title: req.body.article_title,
        article_summary: req.body.article_summary,
        article_content: req.body.article_content,
        article_image: req.file.article_image,
        article_reference: req.body.article_reference
    });
    console.log(article);
    console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);
    article
        .save()
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Saved successfully!");
            res.status(200).json({'article': 'article saved successfully'});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Article save unsuccessful!");
            console.log("article: " + article);
            console.log(req.file);
            console.log(req.body);
            res.status(400).send('adding new article failed');
        });
});
```

However, when I pass a post request on Postman, it fails with a 400 Error saying "Bad Request". As you can see, in the above code, I have many console.logs that shows the value of **req.file** and **req.body** and **article**. When I look on my console, it shows that these values do not include **article_image**. Below is a photo of the console.logs:

[image]

Sorry, for the many code examples, but most of it's just boilerplate code, and the question is simply: Why is my article_image file, which is saving in my image file with Multer, not saving on my MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try `article_image: req.file.path` instead of  `article_image: req.file.article_image`

Comment: Omg, thank you so much! Is there a reason why this works, compared to what I wrote?

Comment: req.file is object and you want to access the `article_image` and there is not this field in req.file, and you should store path of image in DB, the path of file uploaded in `req.file.path`

Comment: Right, that makes sense. It's really strange because a lot of examples online show "req.file.filename" not "req.file.path". Thank you

Comment: when you want to show image to use, you should read image from file, if you have one folder to store imges, you can use filename, but if you store images in different folders, for example, images/user/1.jpeg or images/profile/1.jpeg for access to this images its better store the path

Comment: I have one folder called "images", so is it still okay to store the path?

Comment: yes, you can, but when you want to read images your should try like this: path of folder+ article_image